# Auto logout user based on date in Django

Tags: python, django

I have an expiry date associated with every user, I just want to automatically log out the particular user, if the expiry date has been reached. I'm pretty confused while searching for solutions, some say to use django-session-timeout. Will it work for this type of system?

Comment: create a middleware, do the check there and call `logout(user)`

Comment: I'm not much into middleware in Django, But since I've used express JS. Middleware is something in middle of a chain of events. We should probably trigger it right? How can I actually trigger it? I mean, I don't want to check the date daily or everytime the user uses the app.

Comment: are you identifying user based on some api token ? if yes why not to have a decorator for your resources to check if the token is past expiry date or not.

Comment: The great thing in middleware is it captures all requests. So you can get the user by `request.user`. You can do something like that `if request.user.is_authenticated: logout(user)`